# Reversed DIP Switch

Tags: led, parallel, current-source, switching, series

[image]
Simple question, why does the LED lights up when the switch is off

Comment: Because the switch shorts it out. If I'm reading that mess properly. Draw a schematic instead.

Comment: Take the DIP switch out and see what happens to LED!

Comment: i'm sorry i just started learning electronic. How can i fix this?

Comment: I need to use the DIP tho

Comment: Put the switch in series with everything. Right now it is in parallel with the LED so when it is ON (conducting) it acts as a bypass/detour so current can go around the LED. In series, it acts like a doorway for the current to get to everything else.

Comment: What does it mean that the switch shorts itself out?

Comment: That's the same as saying the bypass/detour thing- a short is a really easy (low resistance path). If you short something out you are placing a really easy path around the thing making a detour.

Comment: A side note, don't short circuit delicate USB equipment, it would not be funny to end up frying USB ports on your devices. Start from AA batteries or lab power supplies as they don't break so easily.

Comment: @DKNguyen, "Put the switch in series with everything" that is voltage supplied... and put the switch in parallel to everything that is current supplied.

Answer (score 13):

This is what your circuit looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f73Ugm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When you close the DIPSW the LED will be shorted thus the current will flow through the DIPSW contacts instead of the LED. So it will turn off.

If you want to turn the LED on when the DIPSW is closed then you should hook up the circuit according to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb8BXR.png)</sup>

Comment: Short circuit through a resistor it is funny)

Comment: @nick_n_a, it's actually a common trick to make a normally open (NO) switch turn something OFF when closed. It is wasteful of power though and in this circuit consumes more power when the LED is off than when it is on!

Comment: How hot does the resistor get, I wonder?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Depending on the type/material/brand/model, any component's surface **temperature rise** (\$\Delta T\$) is directly proportional to the continuous power dissipation. For an average-quality carbon film resistor, \$\Delta T\$ can be as high as 50°C even at 50% of rated power; but it can be as low as 20°C even at 100% of rated power for hi-quality ones. Let's assume a cheap, 0.25W carbon film resistor is used. The power dissipated by that 220R resistor is \$\mathrm{P=V^2/R=5^2/220=110mW}\$. So the **surface temperature** will be \$T=T_{environment}+\Delta T = 24+50=74°C\$.

Comment: This is the right way to do it if you have a current source instead of a voltage source. But then you'd short out resistor and LED together I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

The OP'circuit makes sense; this is the one of the two possible switching topologies - *series* and *parallel* (shunt).

**In the series arrangement**, the load (LED + resistor, lamp, relay, etc.) is supplied by a voltage source. The switch stops/passes the current when is turned off/on. For this purpose, it is connected in series between the load and voltage source.

**In the parallel arrangement**, the load (a bare LED) is supplied by a current source (a voltage source and the resistor in series). The switch passes/diverts ("steers") the current to/from the load when is turned off/on. For this purpose, it is connected in parallel to the load.

To avoid conflicts, a general "switching rule" can be formulated: the current through a voltage-supplied load must be controlled by a series-connected switch while the current through a current-supplied load must be controlled by a parallel-connected switch. Here I mean perfect ("ideal") sources.

Both topologies are widely used in transistor circuits.